# How to count rows by date in mysql and show dynamic headers

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I need to show count of each sources(type colum) and show according to date range

Currently my data is as following

```
id type  date
11 air   2019-10-21 10:00:01
21 air   2019-10-21 10:00:02
31 air   2019-10-21 10:01:03
41 air   2019-10-21 11:01:03
51 air   2019-10-21 12:01:03
61 water 2019-10-21 12:01:03
71 water 2019-10-21 15:01:04
81 water 2019-10-22 16:01:03
81 sea   2019-10-22 16:01:03
81 sea   2019-10-24 16:01:03
```

I want to achive output like the following

```
type 2019-10-21 | 2019-10-22

air     5           0
water   2           1
sea     0           1
```

and also give range in between  2019-10-21 and 2019-10-21

i have tried this query

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when type = ',
      'type',
      ' then type else null end) AS ''',
      date(date), ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM content  where date(`date`) between '2021-02-08' AND '2021-02-10';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT type, ', @sql, '
                   FROM content 
                   GROUP BY type  limit 2');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but it give wrong results and counts the total

```
 type   2021-02-08  2021-02-09  2021-02-10  
    sea        3        3               3   
    air      5316      5316           5316
```

Comment: Maybe `select type, cast(date as date) as d from table group by type, d` would work for you?

Comment: @user3783243 i need colum name as dates too dynamicaly

Comment: Please don't tag me for `anyone else`. Users will post as they view your question. Why does this not achieve the goal? You need 0s for all dates/types that have no data?

Comment: its giving me wrong results its showing same count for all the dates

Comment: Not working that way for me. This is your data? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fea1a3/7